# Problemas com sort() e knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, classificação

https://jsfiddle.net/n8v3hj5n/1/

Eu estou tendo problemas para ordenar uma observableArray do knockoutjs, toda vez que eu mando ordenar a lista ele da um efeito de revese().

Alquem pede resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas, o parâmetro a e b do sort é um objecto, como tal deves de invocar a função como o numero é uma observable :)

Está aqui um exemplo a funcionar, espero que percebas qual foi o erro !

https://jsfiddle.net/n8v3hj5n/2/

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a `funcaoDeComparacao(objA, objB)` do `.sort(funcaoDeComparacao)` espera como retorno um inteiro para definir a ordem do array.

Se ao comparamos dois objetos, a regra de comparação retornar um numero pequeno (em relação as outras comparações), este será movido para o inicio do array.

Se o retorno for um numero maior (que as demais comparações), o mesmo será movido para o final do Array.

Então para facilitar a comparação de objetos, normalmente retornamos `-1` quando `objA` deve aparecer antes do `objB`, `0` quando `objA` é igual ao `objB` ou `1` quando o `objA` deve aparecer depois do `objB`.

note que o `self.numeros` não é um array de inteiros, mas um array de objetos do "tipo" `ranum`, sendo que este possui uma propriedade chamada `numero`, vale notar que `numero` também não é um inteiro, mas uma função que retorna um.

Então para realizar a ordenação da forma esperada, faça da seguinte forma:

```
self.organizar = function() {
  self.numeros.sort(function(a, b) {
    var numeroA = a.numero();
    var numeroB = b.numero();
    return numeroA - numeroB;
  });
}
```